# How to vectorise file reading for an array of filepaths?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, file-io, vectorization

I have a `df` which has a column for absolute file-path strings. I want to read the coordinates, calculate area(of 2 types) and store the areas in another column as `df["area"]`.

I want to use vectorisation as suggested for speed in [this medium article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6).

So the code for the same is (hopefully):

```
df["area"] =   PolyArea(row['filepaths'])
```

Where `PolyArea` is:

```
def PolyArea(urll):
        values = np.loadtxt(urll, skiprows=35,  max_rows=10) #skiprows was suggested on code review*.
        x = values[:,0] 
        y = values[:,1]
        xe = x[:5]     #some compulsory shortening. 
        ye = y[:5] 
        area1 = 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(xe,np.roll(ye,1))-np.dot(ye,np.roll(xe,1)))
        distance = max(np.abs(x[0] - x[3]), np.abs(x[6] - x[9]))
        area2 = area1/distance
        return area1, area2
```

But the error is `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

How can I resolve this error? or How can I Vectorise the `PolyArea` function?

*<sup>https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225442/read-coordinates-from-many-files-and-calculate-polygon-areas/</sup>

Code for generating test files:

```
import numpy as np 
filepath = []
root = '~/Desktop/test/'
for i in range(10):
    name = root + str(i) + ".txt"
    f = open(name,"a")
    for j in range(68):
        numx = np.random.randint(100,200)
        numy = np.random.randint(100,200)
        f.write(str(numx) + " " + str(numy) + "\n")
    f.close()
    filepath.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update `PolyArea` function (Change `return` to `pd.Series`):

```
def PolyArea(urll):
    values = np.loadtxt(urll, skiprows=35,  max_rows=10) #skiprows was suggested on code review*.
    x = values[:,0] 
    y = values[:,1]
    xe = x[:5]     #some compulsory shortening. 
    ye = y[:5] 
    area1 = 0.5*np.abs(np.dot(xe,np.roll(ye,1))-np.dot(ye,np.roll(xe,1)))
    distance = max(np.abs(x[0] - x[3]), np.abs(x[6] - x[9]))
    area2 = area1/distance
    return pd.Series([area1, area2])
```

## Create `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'file_paths' : filepath})
```

## Apply function:

```
df[['area_1', 'area_2']] = df['file_paths'].apply(lambda x: PolyArea(x))
```

## Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing out `series` return. But if you saw the code review question, I want to avoid lambda apply. Can this be done without iterating( under the hood )?

Comment: The difference between that article and this situation is that your data is not inside of the `DataFrame`.  The example in the article is performing a calculation on one set of coordinates.  Your `DataFrame` is rows of files, where each file contains a set of data.

Comment: I am in the hunt of finding an IO method which could take an array of files as input. I will check if this is faster or not.